# Spring Webservice Logging - Remove Binary content

Tags: java, spring, web-services

Is there a way to exclude the binary content out of the Spring's webservice logging. 
We have a system which receives large attachments[MTOM] with webservice response.

Enabling logging level to trace

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing=TRACE
```

dumps all the binary file data in the output log. This also slows down while batch processing.

Changing the log level to `DEBUG` only logs the root webservice response object name and is not useful for debugging.

Looking at the spring code where the response is logged [WebserviceTemplate.logResponse](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-core/2.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.java#702), the method is private and cannot be reached/overridden.

**Is there a way to add like a custom logger or tweak the way spring logs or any other possible way to remove the binary content from webservice responses in logs?**

P.S. I also tried re-generating the webservice client classes with [XJC2Task](https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin)
with the -XToString option, just hoping that if setting the `MessageTracing=DEBUG` would log the full content of the webservice response root object [by using toString]. But that didnt happen and Spring would only log the object name.

Comment: Did you find any suggestions for this topic ? thanks in advance